# Navigation to certain View when notification arrive when app is closed React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

- How to make navigation to certain View/Screen in Mobile App, when notification received when mobile application is closed ?
- **Platform** 
  *react native v0.61.5*
  *notification package* =>

> react-native-firebase v6.2.0
>   react-native-push-notification v3.1.9

*react-navigation v4.0.10*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61041586/11380693 does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NavigationActions** from **react-navigation**.

App.js

```
<AppContainer
  ref={navigatorRef => {
  NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);}}/>
```

NavigationService.js

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
 _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName,
    params,
    })
  );
 }

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator
 }
```

Now in **onNotificationOpened** function from firebase you have to write one line.

```
NavigationService.navigate('your screen', { param:paramValue })
```

Answer (score 0):

//**You can send data with the notification in this format**

{
"to" : "FCM_token",
"collapse_key" : "type_a",
"notification" : {
"body" : "Testing",
"title": "Test Title"

},
"data" : {
"name" : "xyz"
}
}

//**Now you can get data in listener**

const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();

if (notificationOpen) {

```
    let {name} = notificationOpen.notification._data;
    
    console.log("Notification data - ", name);
    setInitialRoute(name);
```

}

//**Now to declare state variable and change the initialRoute of the navigator....**

const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState('ABC');

setInitialRoute(name);    // **in the notification listener**

//**Now use in Navigation container**

```
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRoute}>

  </Stack.Navigator>
```